# Understanding systemd dependencies on auto-created device units

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd unit ("leafnode.socket") that depends on a network device ("rath") being up. The socket unit has an explicit file in /etc, the device unit is (I believe) automatically created by systemd in response to udev events:

```
root@ebox ~# cat /etc/systemd/system/leafnode.socket
[Unit]
Description=NNTP server for small sites (socket)

[Socket]
ListenStream=119
BindToDevice=rath
Accept=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

At boot, the device comes up fine, but the socket does not:

```
root@ebox /e/s/system# systemctl status leafnode.socket
○ leafnode.socket - NNTP server for small sites (socket)
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/leafnode.socket; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
     Listen: [::]:119 (Stream)
   Accepted: 0; Connected: 0;

Feb 14 09:09:08 ebox.rath.org systemd[1]: Dependency failed for leafnode.socket - NNTP server for small sites (socket).
Feb 14 09:09:08 ebox.rath.org systemd[1]: leafnode.socket: Job leafnode.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.

root@ebox /e/s/system# systemctl status sys-subsystem-net-devices-rath.device
● sys-subsystem-net-devices-rath.device - /sys/subsystem/net/devices/rath
     Loaded: loaded
     Active: active (plugged) since Wed 2024-02-14 09:09:08 UTC; 8min ago
     Device: /sys/devices/virtual/net/rath
```

If I manually start the socket at this point, it comes up just fine.

Can someone help me understand what is going wrong here? As far as I can tell, the socket unit gets an implicit dependency on the device unit and should therefore come up just fine. In practice, systemd seems to somehow determine that the dependency "failed" - and indeed, there's a corresponding time-out message for the .device:

```
root@ebox /e/s/system# journalctl -u sys-subsystem-net-devices-rath.device
Feb 14 09:09:08 ebox.rath.org systemd[1]: sys-subsystem-net-devices-rath.device: Job sys-subsystem-net-devices-rath.device/start timed out.
Feb 14 09:09:08 ebox.rath.org systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device sys-subsystem-net-devices-rath.device - /sys/subsystem/net/devices/rath.
Feb 14 09:09:08 ebox.rath.org systemd[1]: sys-subsystem-net-devices-rath.device: Job sys-subsystem-net-devices-rath.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
```

However, since this unit is only created once there is an udev event for it, I don't understand how it can possibly "time out". Doesn't the mere fact that systemd receives an event for it mean that its there, and there is nothing that needs to be waited for?